# Low Cost, Server, Linux 4.x Graphics card with support for 4k for graphics consolee

Tags: linux, 4k

looking for a native Linux 4.x kernel supported 4K capable graphics card for occasional graphical console admin work.

I share a massive 55" 4K TV between my workstations and savers, and it grates me to work on the servers at 1920x4080 with gnomes 'Kindergarten' sized native text and icons. At 4K the entire output is reasonable and pleasant, but only my workstations have cards capable of driving that.

Looking for a recommendation on what to get that I can purchase 2nd hand as cheap as possible from ebay.

The price-cutoff point is what I use today for 2x Linux workstations I have - AMD RX 560 at ~$80 from ebay.

I was hoping for something much cheaper - $20-$40 range.

Comment: GT710 should do that as well (@30Hz).  There are plenty of new ones available too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few seconds after posting I got my answer - AMD R7 250 available from $30 will do the trick.